# Why in memory mode donot accelerate in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, optimization, in-memory-database, sql-execution-plan

There is a query that scans full table, there are 5million records, it costs about 60s. How to optimize this?
I have tried to use memory mode of sqlite, in theory this should be faster, since whole database is stored in memroy. However, it costs almost the same time.
table schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl0(estimateid int, seq int,  field1 int NULL, field2 int NULL,  field3 int NULL,  field4 int NULL);
CREATE INDEX tbl0_idx on tbl0(estimateid);
CREATE TABLE tbl1(seq int, companyid int, field1 int NULL, field2 int NULL,  field3 int NULL,  field4 int NULL, field5 int NULL);
CREATE INDEX tbl1_idx on tbl1(seq);
CREATE TABLE tbl2(symbolid int, relatedcompanyid int,  value char(64),  field1 int NULL, field2 int NULL,  field3 int NULL,  field4 int NULL, field5 int NULL);
CREATE INDEX tbl2_idx on tbl2(relatedcompanyid);
```

and this is query, query that need join 3 tables:

```
>explain query plan select tbl0.estimateid, tbl1.seq, tbl1.companyid, tbl2.value from tbl0, tbl1, tbl2 where tbl0.seq = tbl1.seq and tbl1.companyid = tbl2.relatedcompanyid;
0|0|1|SCAN TABLE tbl1
0|1|2|SEARCH TABLE tbl2 USING INDEX tbl2_idx (relatedcompanyid=?)
0|2|0|SEARCH TABLE tbl0 USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (seq=?)
```

How to accelerate this query? Seems it's inevitable one table will be fully scanned.  Each table contains about 5million records, this query costs very long time(several minutes). 
When I put db in memory, use this #sqlite3 :memory:,  it doesnot make any difference in speed. 
Help is very appreciated.

Comment: To optimize this, don't scan 5 million records.

Answer (score 1):

A **full index scan** (type: index) is according to the documentation is the 2nd worst possible execution plan after a **full table scan**, which you chosen.

Full table scan is resource-intensive operation for DB, and there's no magic behind the scenes unless you boost your memory, CPU speed, will index the table, will reduce the number of records, etc. That's why you haven't noticed any drastic speed increase when you moved everything to the memory.

You should try to avoid this and to make the better query, or to optimize the DB and tables structures. Please, reference [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) and [Query Planning](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) for getting more details on the execution of your SQL and how it can be optimized.

It's hard to say more and to be more specific, as in your original question you haven't provided the DB structures, the characteristics of your data, your query, etc.

Comment: Can you tell me how to accelerate that join query above? Seems one table will be fully scaned, how can I determine which table will be scanned, If I can, I could reduce records of tbl2, and tell sqlite to scan tbl2, search tbl1 and tbl0. In this way, query will be faster I think.

Comment: @wushiqi, in your case, I'd recommend to use properly indexes for your tables, right now - it does the full table scan just because to find the value - it needs to search the whole data. Indexes are special lookup tables that the database search engine can use to speed up data retrieval. If in short: columns, which are used for tables joins - are normally the perfect candidates, as well as columns which are frequently used as a lookup criteria.

Comment: I have created index as shown above. Could you tell me how to optimize this? Now each table contains 5 million records, and this query costs 300s and produces 300,000,000 records in total.  I am very longing for optimization.   Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your database is not in memory; you've done something wrong.  I built a program to load 5 million records in another in-memory database system and it took less than 800 milliseconds for a full sequential scan.  Even if SQLite is only half as fast as the in-memory database system I used, it should only take a second or two.

another possibility is you're writing to the console after fetching every row, or performing some other logic, that is causing the overall slowness.